# Decrease the length between title and content of resume

Tags: vertical-alignment, lengths

```
\documentclass[11.8pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.88]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     
% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{123 ABC St}{City, State zip code}   
\mobile{9876543219}                   
\email{johndoe@xmail.com}                     

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

How can I decrease the vertical length between the personal data section and `\maketitle`?

Comment: Welcome! Why aren't you using `\makecvtitle`? rather than `\maketitle`? I guess they do the same thing, though. Just the example I looked at used the former. I seriously doubt that `11.8pt` does anything at all.

Comment: I assume it is just the same as `11pt` or else `11pt` is default.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11.8pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{verbatim,lipsum}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.88]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     
% personal data

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{123 ABC St}{City, State zip code}   
\mobile{9876543219}                   
\email{johndoe@xmail.com} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle     
\vspace*{-8mm}%decrease the vertical length between the personal data section and \maketitle
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```